# Git / Stash Pull Request overwriting newer changes

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

We are tyring to use GitFlow along with Stash but have come across a problem where a pull request wants to overrwite newer changes!?

I have a git repo that has 4 images in it along with some code. After initial commit and setup, master and develop branches were identical **(1)**. The repo was then branched (from develop) into feature/F1 **(2)**.

A hotifx branch was made (from master) and work was done to update the images (logo updates). This was then merged into master and down into develop.

Now, the team is wanting to merge the work in feature/F1 back into develop. The pull request in Stash is trying to change the images back to what they were when the branch was taken??

How can i find out what we have done wrong? it doesnt inspire confidence in it..

Merging develop changes into the feature branch has no effect on the images.

I checked all commits in the branch and the images weren't touched other than the merge from develop to get latest changes. The source files still show as the old images?

Comment: I think your question is so wage. It will be better for all to explain with simple pictorial representation.. It would help you to get them fixed soon

Comment: i created a diagram but SO wont let me attach images - my rep is too low. I cant be bothered to do it with characters. Ill talk to atlassian instead thanks anyways :)Set to answered.

Comment: Are you sure the changes are on your feature branch, are not on the develop branch and that the pull request is _from_ the feature branch _to_ develop? If so, it certainly should show your changes from the feature branch.

Comment: Stash and sourcetree both show a merge from develop to the feature to get the updated image change. You can see the before and after in both too.

However when you do git history on the image files in the branch you only get the initial commit entry.

Comment: Atlassians support said that 'something' must have gone wrong with the merge. 

I did a git cherrypick to get the updated image commits applied to my branch.

I still dont know what went wrong with the merge (the dev that did it doesnt know either).